# Select records having category_id somewhere in the category tree

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm displaying a tree of categories and, next to each branch I want a count of the number of listings which are the same level, or lower.

All listings have a catid which is at the lowest category level. i.e. you can't apply a particular catid to a listing if there are lower category levels available.

As an example, in the "listings" table below, you can't find a listing that has catid = 24 because this is not yet the lowest level in the tree along that branch.

In my categories database, there are a maximum 4 levels (0-3).

Here are the tables:

**all_categories** (table)

```
record_id  parent_category_id   parent_id  title        level
--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
24         NULL                 NULL       Real Estate  0
5915       24                   24         Residential  1
7569       5915                 24         For sale     2
```

**listings** (table)

```
record_id    cat_id
--------------------
1            7569
2            8847
```

So, my category tree in HTML should looks something like this:

**HTML**

```
Categories              Listing count
-------------------------------------
24                      1
  5915                  1
    7569                1
```

So, in my html and jQuery code, I pass a particular catid of any level to the query and it should find listings that are at or below that level.

I've been trying for hours and my efforts so far aren't worth showing. But I will anyway...

EDIT: My effort so far (don't laugh, it's muddled after hours of trying different things):

```
select l.record_id 
from listings l
where catid in (
    select record_id 
    from all_categories 
    where record_id = 5915)
or catid in (
    select parent_category_id 
    from all_categories 
    where parent_category_id = 5915)
or catid in (
    select parent_id 
    from all_categories 
    where parent_id = 5915)
```

Comment: SQL question generally require carefully chosen minimal yet complete sample data (covering all the edge cases), and **corresponding expected output** in tabular form. Do read this once: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308

Comment: What version do you have?  This task may be easier with MySQL 8.0's "Recursive CTEs".

Comment: Do you want to display empty categories (categories with no listings)?

Answer (score 1):

The level 0 parent_id for a child is kept in the "all_categories" table.

So a child can be linked to the other childs by their common parent_id.
And then include the level 0 at the same time.

The difficulty is when the given child id isn't in the "listings" table.
So to retrieve that listings record_id, it has to go via the categories.

A test on rextester can be found [here](https://rextester.com/YMJN72013)

```sql
SELECT 
cat.record_id as catId, 
pl.listId AS ListingCount,
cat.level
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
     cat1.parent_id, 
     MAX(list.record_id) AS listId
    FROM all_categories AS cat1
    JOIN all_categories AS cat2 ON cat2.parent_id = cat1.parent_id
    JOIN listings list ON list.cat_id = cat2.record_id
    WHERE cat1.record_id = 5915
    GROUP BY cat1.parent_id
) AS pl
LEFT JOIN all_categories AS cat ON (cat.parent_id = pl.parent_id OR cat.record_id = pl.parent_id)
ORDER BY cat.record_id, cat.level;
```

Result:

```
catId   ListingCount    level
24      1               0
5915    1               1
7569    1               2
```

The "level" is also included in the query, because that can be used to generate that category tree in HTML.

Note that the query could be simplified a lot if that "listings" table would only contain the cat_id for the level 0

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the tree is maximum four level deep you can use multiple LEFT JOINs to retrieve the full tree or a sub-tree. This won't be super efficient though. Consider the following query:

```
SET @subtree_id = 1;

SELECT
    c0.category_id AS c0_id, c0.name AS c0_name,
    c1.category_id AS c1_id, c1.name AS c1_name,
    c2.category_id AS c2_id, c2.name AS c2_name,
    c3.category_id AS c3_id, c3.name AS c3_name,
    l.listing_id
FROM category AS c0
LEFT JOIN category AS c1 ON c1.parent_id = c0.category_id
LEFT JOIN category AS c2 ON c2.parent_id = c1.category_id
LEFT JOIN category AS c3 ON c3.parent_id = c2.category_id
LEFT JOIN listing AS l ON l.category_id = c0.category_id
                       OR l.category_id = c1.category_id
                       OR l.category_id = c2.category_id
                       OR l.category_id = c3.category_id
WHERE c0.category_id = @subtree_id;
```

It will produce results such as this:

```
| c0_id | c0_name     | c1_id | c1_name     | c2_id | c2_name   | c3_id | c3_name    | listing_id |
|-------|-------------|-------|-------------|-------|-----------|-------|------------|------------|
| 1     | Real Estate | 2     | Residential | 3     | House     | NULL  | NULL       | NULL       |
| 1     | Real Estate | 2     | Residential | 4     | Apartment | NULL  | NULL       | 1          |
| 1     | Real Estate | 2     | Residential | 4     | Apartment | NULL  | NULL       | 2          |
| 1     | Real Estate | 2     | Residential | 4     | Apartment | NULL  | NULL       | 3          |
| 1     | Real Estate | 2     | Residential | 5     | Condo     | NULL  | NULL       | NULL       |
| 1     | Real Estate | 6     | Commercial  | 7     | Office    | NULL  | NULL       | 4          |
| 1     | Real Estate | 6     | Commercial  | 8     | Retail    | NULL  | NULL       | 5          |
| 1     | Real Estate | 6     | Commercial  | 9     | Other     | 10    | Industrial | 6          |
```

Unfortunately it contains full paths only. To match the expected result just break each row into 4 rows:

```
SET @subtree_id = 1;

SELECT
    CASE WHEN level >= 0 THEN c0_id END AS c0_id, CASE WHEN level >= 0 THEN c0_name END AS c0_name,
    CASE WHEN level >= 1 THEN c1_id END AS c1_id, CASE WHEN level >= 1 THEN c1_name END AS c1_name,
    CASE WHEN level >= 2 THEN c2_id END AS c2_id, CASE WHEN level >= 2 THEN c2_name END AS c2_name,
    CASE WHEN level >= 3 THEN c3_id END AS c3_id, CASE WHEN level >= 3 THEN c3_name END AS c3_name,
    COUNT(listing_id) AS lc
FROM (
    SELECT
        c0.category_id AS c0_id, c0.name AS c0_name,
        c1.category_id AS c1_id, c1.name AS c1_name,
        c2.category_id AS c2_id, c2.name AS c2_name,
        c3.category_id AS c3_id, c3.name AS c3_name,
        l.listing_id
    FROM category AS c0
    LEFT JOIN category AS c1 ON c1.parent_id = c0.category_id
    LEFT JOIN category AS c2 ON c2.parent_id = c1.category_id
    LEFT JOIN category AS c3 ON c3.parent_id = c2.category_id
    LEFT JOIN listing AS l ON l.category_id = c0.category_id
                           OR l.category_id = c1.category_id
                           OR l.category_id = c2.category_id
                           OR l.category_id = c3.category_id
    WHERE c0.category_id = @subtree_id
) AS paths
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 0 AS level UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3
) AS levels ON level = 0 AND c0_id IS NOT NULL
            OR level = 1 AND c1_id IS NOT NULL
            OR level = 2 AND c2_id IS NOT NULL
            OR level = 3 AND c3_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
ORDER BY 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7
```

[Demo on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=08f34bc7c07620ff3aa93a2812ab342d)

Answer (score 1):

You have an arcane data structure, but the problem doesn't seem that hard.  This seems to do what you want:

```
select c2.record_id, count(*)
from listings l join
         all_categories c
         on l.cat_id = c.record_id join
         all_categories c2
         on c2.record_id in (c.record_id, c.parent_category_id, c.parent_id)
group by c2.record_id, l.cat_id
order by l.cat_id, c2.record_id;
```

The idea is pretty simple.  The table `all_categories` has the full hierarchy.  Basically, you need to move all the levels of the hierarchy into separate *rows* so they can be aggregated.

That is what the `join` to `c2` does.  The rest is just aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

well in mysql 8 there is a (with) function which run recursively you can get the level of the catId

> structure -> (id cat parent_id)
>   ->(1,24,NULL),(2,5915,1),(3,7569,2),(4,3,1)

```
WITH recursive parent(id,parent_id,Levels) AS
(
    select id,parent_id, 0 as Levels from table where id =1 //condition
    union all
    select c.id,c.parent_id,(Levels+1) as Levels from table as c  inner join parent as p1 on p1.id = c.parent_id
)
SELECT *
FROM  parent
```

the only limitation of this is that it is in my sql version 8.x rest the code will run fine any problem you can ask this method is called cet hope it help

Answer (score 0):

For each record_id, left-join the children, then count the unique values at each level and add them together.

```
select n.record_id
count(distinct n.record_id)+count(distinct n2.record_id)+count(distinct 
n3.record_id)+count(distinct n4.record_id) listingcount
from all_categories n
left join all_categories n2 on n.record_id=n2.parent_category_id
left join all_categories n3 on n2.record_id=n3.parent_category_id
left join all_categories n4 on n3.record_id=n4.parent_category_id
group by n.record_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is suited for a recursive sql.

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_total_listings(@root_id INT) RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @listing_count INT;
    WITH cat (record_id, parent_category_id) AS
    (
        SELECT root.record_id, root.parent_category_id
        FROM all_categories AS root
        WHERE root.parent_category_id = @root_id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT child.record_id, child.parent_category_id
        FROM cat AS parent, all_categories AS child
        WHERE parent.record_id = child.parent_category_id
    )
    SELECT @listing_count = count(*)
    FROM listings l
    JOIN cat ON l.cat_id = cat.record_id;
    RETURN @listing_count;
END;

SELECT record_id, f_total_listings(record_id) FROM all_categories
```